# Vaadin modal subwindow components are dithered as if inactive

Tags: window, vaadin

Vaadin 6.8.13

No matter where in my program I call any type of modal subwindow in my application, the subwindow is dithered as if it's not active. I can still select the components on the table and do everything as if it was active.  I have tested this in several different browsers as well.  I didn't do anything that I'm aware of that would have changed the color scheme or modified the subwindow.

I have had a few issues in the past where I click to open a subwindow once and it opens two subwindows or more and I have to close them out, but the top one was always in focus.  I cannot find any additional subwindows open in this instance.  This is constant across my program.

Example code:

```
    final Window subwindow = new Window(sectionName);
    subwindow.setModal(true);
    subwindow.setImmediate(true);

    final VerticalLayout windowLayout = (VerticalLayout) subwindow.getContent();
    windowLayout.setMargin(true);
    windowLayout.setSpacing(true);
    windowLayout.setSizeUndefined();

    <Adding content to subwindow>

    getWindow().addWindow(subwindow);
    subwindow.focus();
```

It is slightly less dithered than the main application window, but it's not clear as it should be. (I tried to post an image, but my reputation is not high enough)

Any suggestions on where to look or what could be causing this behavior?

Update:
I ran the debug tool on the window and got the following information:

```
-com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.ui.VWindow id=PID441 immediate=true caption=Stakeholder Section name= theme=phantom-theme modal=true resizable=true sub=true
-variables
tabindex=-1
scrollLeft=0
scrollTop=0
positionx=606
positiony=376
close=false
-com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.ui.VVerticalLayout id=PID442 margins=15 spacing=true alignments={PID443:34,} expandRatios={}
-com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.ui.VVerticalLayout id=PID443 margins=0 spacing=true alignments={PID444:48,PID448:34,} expandRatios={}
-com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.ui.VTabsheet id=PID444 immediate=true
-variables
selected=1
-tabs
-tab caption=Main key=1 selected=true
-com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.ui.VVerticalLayout id=PID445 margins=14 alignments={} expandRatios={}
-com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.ui.VHorizontalLayout id=PID446 margins=0 spacing=true alignments={} expandRatios={}
-com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.ui.VTreeTable id=PID447 height=44px style=striped animate=true selectmode=none cols=3 rows=1 firstrow=0 totalrows=1 pagelength=2 colheaders=true colfooters=false vcolorder={0:1,1:2,2:3,} pb-ft=0 pb-l=0
-variables
firstvisible=0
firstvisibleonlastpage=-1
sortcolumn=1
sortascending=true
reqrows=-1
reqfirstrow=-1
-rows
-tr key=1 depth=0 style-1=normal style-2=red style-3=yellow
Stakeholder Section
4
8
-visiblecolumns
-column cid=1 caption=Section fcaption= sortable=true
-column cid=2 caption=Johnny Importante fcaption= sortable=true width=119
-column cid=3 caption=Susie Tech fcaption= sortable=true width=119
-com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.ui.VHorizontalLayout id=PID448 margins=0 spacing=true alignments={PID449:10,} expandRatios={}
-com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.ui.VButton id=PID449 style=small default caption=Close
-variables
state=false
```

I'm wondering if "state=false" may be related?

Update 2:
It appears that this only affects viewing in Safari.  I have tried in FireFox and IE and don't experience the issue.  I have cleared the cache in Safari and that didn't help.